# IIS virtual directory root path redirect for PHP

Tags: php, iis, directory, virtual

I have a PHP website hosted on IIS 8.

The site is hosted on the default site, in a virtual directory.

Example:
http://192.168.1.1/virtual/index.php

The web page loads correctly, the problem is with the URLs, CSS and JS.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery/jquery-1.11.0.min.js">/script>
```

will refer to:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://192.168.1.1/js/jquery/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

This causes 404 errors and the pages don't load correctly - as it is referring to the parent of the virtual directory.
This is a PHP CMS, and I cannot go and modify each and every url.

I have tried using all sorts of redirects in web.config, with no success.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly you would want to ensure that all the JS and CSS links still hit the same path but within the virtual directory. I think this rewrite should work, make sure it gets added in the web.config of the root site and not the web.config of virtual directory:

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="css_js_to_virtual">
                <match url="(.*).(js|css)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/virtual/{R:0}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```